# Response time of the Query executed using JMeter differs from the response time when the same query is executed on a different source

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter to verify the performance (Response time) of a MySql Query.
While testing I observed the following:

1. When I execute a "Mysql Query" (In my case the query was a select statement) from "puTTY command" the response time is 0.09s.
   Please refer the Screenshot attached below:
   [image]
2. when I execute the "same Query" using the JDBC Request Sampler the response time is 4974 ms(i.e 4.974 s)
   Please refer the Screenshot attached below:
   [image]

There is a dissimilarity in the response time.
I am not able to understand why ??
One thing that I thought of is:

To get the actual query execution time should I do the following
Sample time(ms)-connect time(ms)

Am I right, I am new to JMeter please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in case of MySQL command-line client you are **already** connected to the database and in case of JMeter query execution time includes the time required to set up the database connection.

You can work it around by adding [JDBC PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PreProcessor) using the same "Variable Name" and execute some form of validation query, i.e. `SELECT 1` as a child of your main JDBC Request sampler.

By default JMeter doesn't include the time taken by pre/post processors and timers into main sample so using this workaround you will be able to exclude the time required to establish the connection from the load test results.

See [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) article to learn more about the concept of database load testing using JMeter

Answer (score 0):

Sample time represent the time between the sending of the request and the complete receipt of the reply but you should consider the Connect time.
So the response time of your query will be : Sample Time - Connect time